# Specified child already has a parent error. Only occurs if called in different loop

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, parent-child

I am trying to make a sort linearlayout for android. However, to sort the layout, it needs to be sorted before adding it to the layout. However, if i want to add the objects lateron, it says the child already has a parent. It seems like they are assigned a parent automatically. This is the normal code which works fine:

```
    post_list = new ArrayList<Post>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Post post = new Post(this, "#4c66a4", "#FFFFFF");
        post_list.add(post);

        View list = (View) post.show();
        ll.addView(list, layoutParams);
    }
```

However, when I want to add the view later, it is not possible anymore:

```
    post_list = new ArrayList<Post>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Post post = new Post(this, "#4c66a4", "#FFFFFF");
        post_list.add(post);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < post_list.size(); i++) {
        Post p = post_list.get(i);
        View list = (View) p.show();
        ll.addView(list, layoutParams);

    }
```

Any idea how this problem is caused?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `p.show()` do? If it returns the same view it returned previously, of course it has already been added to a parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to discover the cause of the added parent, we need to see logcat and more code. It's likely this is the cause, though:

["specified child already has a parent" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025180/specified-child-already-has-a-parent-error?rq=1)

But if you're just trying to "force" add the view, then call this before adding it:

```
((ViewGroup)list.getParent()).removeView(list);
```

to remove the view from its parent and add it where you like.

Comment: Just rebooten and for some reason it suddenly worked. THank you for the response